# Alias <-----> does not exist

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, maps, keystore, keytool

this is my first time of trying to sign a map and i get this error from my mac terminal saying alias <----->does not exist am trying to get my MD5 from my mac using the key tool. i have google for a while now, thank you , i will be here waiting for your response

Comment: can add the exact command you are you using?

Comment: keytool -list -alias <------> -keystore <------>.keystore , this is what am using

Comment: I assume the <------> is the actual alias you are using? This sounds like you haven't set up the keystore yet? Are you trying to use the default keystore or is this for your actual application?

Comment: @akhalsa thank you for your response, i have actually set up my keystore using my eclispe, am not using the default keystone either.

Comment: after doing all these, am trying to get my new MD5 from my terminal to be able to publish it, but i get Alias <---->does not exist, @akhalsa i really need to get away from this point i have been here for a week, trying to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using Eclipse, I suggest the following:

1. In Eclipse, go to Window -> Preferences.
2. Click on Android -> Build.
3. You will see  an entry for `Default debug keystore` and the directory/file that it is currently present in.

That is file you need to be firing those `keytool` commands on. The -keystore parameter will point to the file you see in step 3 above.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have the alias wrong from eclipse, or actually if I had to guess, the file location wrong. I'd try making a new keystore and doing it again. Based on what you're saying the error is, I would be shocked if the problem was not in your alias/keystore setup being consistent with the command you are using. IE having the alias wrong, or improperly pointing at the keystore you created etc. Unfortunately, without more details on how exactly you setup your keystore and where you are running the command from etc, it is impossible to debug further from here. If you cannot fix it on your own, I'd suggest taking some screenshots of setting up the keystore and then write down the exact command you are using for the keytool  and posting them.

Comment: please can you send me like a process of how this should be done from start to finish, how am to sign it properly, this could help me